# Data won't retrieve from firebase but doesn't show errors

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i wanted to retrieve my data from firebase to listview android studio. It has no errors on logcat, but the data won't show on the listview. Here is the code from the model:

```
public class Transaksi {

    private String namaPemesan;
    private String tglMasuk;
    private String tglSelesai;
    private String namaPenerima;

    public List<Transaksi> getTransaksiList() {
        return transaksiList;
    }

    public void setTransaksiList(List<Transaksi> transaksiList) {
        this.transaksiList = transaksiList;
    }

    private List<Transaksi> transaksiList;

    public String getNamaPemesan() {
        return namaPemesan;
    }

    public void setNamaPemesan(String namaPemesan) {
        this.namaPemesan = namaPemesan;
    }

    public String getTglMasuk() {
        return tglMasuk;
    }

    public void setTglMasuk(String tglMasuk) {
        this.tglMasuk = tglMasuk;
    }

    public String getTglSelesai() {
        return tglSelesai;
    }

    public void setTglSelesai(String tglSelesai) {
        this.tglSelesai = tglSelesai;
    }

    public String getNamaPenerima() {
        return namaPenerima;
    }

    public void setNamaPenerima(String namaPenerima) {
        this.namaPenerima = namaPenerima;
    }

    public Transaksi(String namaPemesan, String tglMasuk, String tglSelesai, String namaPenerima) {
        this.namaPemesan = namaPemesan;
        this.tglMasuk = tglMasuk;
        this.tglSelesai = tglSelesai;
        this.namaPenerima = namaPenerima;
    }
}
```

This the adapter:

```
public class TransaksiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Transaksi> {

    public TransaksiAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Transaksi> transaksiArrayList){
        super (context, R.layout.list_transaksi, transaksiArrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row =  convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            row = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_transaksi, parent, false);

            Transaksi currentTransaksi = getItem(position);
            TextView txtTglMasuk = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detail_tgl_masuk);
            txtTglMasuk.setText(currentTransaksi.getTglMasuk());

            TextView txtTglKeluar = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detail_tgl_keluar);
            txtTglKeluar.setText(currentTransaksi.getTglSelesai());

            TextView txtPemesan = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detail_pemesan);
            txtPemesan.setText(currentTransaksi.getNamaPemesan());

            TextView txtPenerima = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detail_penerima);
            txtPenerima.setText(currentTransaksi.getNamaPenerima());
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

And this is the activity:

```
public class ListTransaksiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private ListView listViewTransaksi;

    ArrayList<Transaksi> trksArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    TransaksiAdapter transaksiAdapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_transaksi);

        transaksiAdapter = new TransaksiAdapter(this, R.layout.list_transaksi, trksArrayList);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://rewanglaundry-ec6e9-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/").getReference("Laundry");
        listViewTransaksi = findViewById(R.id.listView_Transaksi);

        listViewTransaksi.setAdapter(transaksiAdapter);

        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Transaksi value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Transaksi.class);
                trksArrayList.add(value);
                transaksiAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                transaksiAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "Laundry" : {
    "1626021441819" : {
      "keranjang" : [ {
        "harga" : "10000",
        "id" : 13,
        "namaJenis" : "KILOAN GOSOK",
        "quantity" : "2"
      }, {
        "harga" : "9000",
        "id" : 14,
        "namaJenis" : "KILOAN CUCI",
        "quantity" : "2"
      }, {
        "harga" : "5000",
        "id" : 15,
        "namaJenis" : "KILOAN GOSOK",
        "quantity" : "1"
      } ],
      "namaPemesan" : "Jumi",
      "namaPenerima" : "Ten",
      "tglMasuk" : "11-07-2021",
      "tglSelesai" : "14-07-2021",
      "totalHarga" : "24000"
    },
    "1626264517918" : {
      "keranjang" : [ {
        "harga" : "8000",
        "id" : 16,
        "namaJenis" : "KAOS",
        "quantity" : "1"
      }, {
        "harga" : "9000",
        "id" : 17,
        "namaJenis" : "KILOAN CUCI",
        "quantity" : "2"
      } ],
      "namaPemesan" : "Toni",
      "namaPenerima" : "Tuki",
      "tglMasuk" : "07-07-2021",
      "tglSelesai" : "10-07-2021",
      "totalHarga" : "17000"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using database location region asia, so i put the link on the getInstance. But it still wont show the data from firebase.
Any help is appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: Can you do logcat for each every method `onChild`. ..

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: What does `1626021441819` that exists under `Laundry` represent?

Comment: i think thats the auto id for the parent of each Laundry order @AlexMamo

Comment: If you try to stop ignoring errors and use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: i got this error `Class com.example.rewanglaundry.Model.Transaksi does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.`

Comment: I recommend [searching for that error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+Class+does+not+define+a+no-argument+constructor) in relation to Firebase, as it's been covered regularly before. You'll need to add a no-argument constructor to your `Transaksi` class, so `public Transaksi() {}`.